# Image recognition mouse-click automation utility?

Tags: mac, automation

Does there exist any kind of a simple MacOSX utility that can take a given image and find whether the image is on the screen (perhaps with a certain variance threshold) and then automate a position of the mouse cursor and/or click on the area which matches the image?

Please don't respond about how this is a terrible idea and shouldn't be done. This is an important task for testing and cannot be easily accomplished by triggering events or the like.

Comment: And, for the record, this really *isn't* such an awful idea. It's actually a neat one, seeing as how some things are, like you said, easier scriptable this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/). It does just what you want, looks for images and clicks them. It uses a simple scripting language so it can do other things, other than just clicking. Such as typing into a text box.